Auto increment numbers if elements are not siblings
Is it possible - with css only - to auto increment numbers if elements are not siblings?
Something like this?


.numbers {
    counter-increment: item;

    &::before {
        content: counter(item) ":";
    }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="numbers"></div>
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="numbers"></div>
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="numbers"></div>
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="numbers"></div>
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



And if not, what is the best and most efficient way to achieve it? JavaScript?

Instread of incrementing your counter with .numbers, you can do it with the parent.


.col {
  counter-increment: item;
}

.numbers:before {
  content: counter(item) ":";
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="numbers"></div>
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="numbers"></div>
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="numbers"></div>
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="numbers"></div>
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



